# GeneratedValue not recognizing existing hibernate_sequence

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have this User class

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
}
```

And this is the logs when running the Application

```
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists user cascade
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: sequence "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table user (id int8 not null, primary key (id))
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
```

And here is my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

My understanding on logs is it was looking for hibernate_sequence for it to continue to create User table.

I tried looking into the database used and hibernate_sequence was automatically created - hence, the error should not be produced.

**EDIT 1**

I tried not to use sequence and use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` strategy instead but still unable to create table user.

**EDIT 2**

This is my whole build.gradle if version might be an issue on this too.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')

    compile('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc4')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the sequence... `user` is a reserved keyword in postgres. You have to explicitly define another table name with the `@Table` keyword on your `User` entity.

Comment: thanks. I tried changing the  User to another word and it works. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

To use Sequence strategy for generating id it's necessary to define the sequence generator first. For example:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="my_seq")
    private Long id;

    //...
}
```

More info is [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated#The_Sequence_Strategy_).

Comment: I tried using that but it seemed like it doesn't do anything. The logs still shows the same and `my_seq` is not created too.

Comment: Check your 'resource' folder - maybe there is a `schema*.sql` file in it?

Comment: M. Deinum is right. It was due to the `User` keyword of postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `hibernate.hbm2ddl=update` and the hibernate_sequence will be created.